# EWS operation to edit Distribution list

Tags: exchangewebservices, distribution-list

I am looking for an EWS operation to edit a Distribution list. Here edit means, adding\deleting a existing contact into\from an existing group or changing Display Name of Group.

I have tried option like mentioned in following link:- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/db110c4e-a0f2-40de-9276-3e30458b254f/ews-maximum-number-of-members-in-a-contact-group?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Also used properties like AppendToItemField, SetItemField and DeleteItemField?But error comes as "The method or operation is not implemented"

Comment: What version of Exchange are you using ? on 2010 up you should be using the ContactGroup operations. You should also post the code your using if any if you want assistance.

Comment: I have tried with Exchange Version 2007 to Exchange 2013. I haven't done any coding yet for the EWS operation, I am just using SOAP xml Request Response format for finding the suitable match for Address Book Group EWS operation

Comment: You need to use Exchange 2010 and if your using SOAP you will need to use versioing in your headers to tell the server this is a 2010 request.

Comment: Yes I am explicitly mentioning Server Version in EWS header. But didn't work. But now I have found 1 Request format that worked for me. Will soon post the same here once I verify all the operation thoroughly. Thanks Glen Scales for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer for Editing Groups. here is SOAP call which worked for me:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <UpdateItem ConflictResolution="AutoResolve" MessageDisposition="SaveOnly" SendMeetingInvitationsOrCancellations="SendToNone" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
      <ItemChanges>
        <t:ItemChange>
          <t:ItemId Id="AAMkADZmMjJlMDk...." ChangeKey="EgAAAB..." />
          <t:Updates>
            <t:AppendToItemField>
              <t:FieldURI FieldURI="distributionlist:Members" />
              <t:DistributionList>
                <t:Members>
                  <t:Member>
                    <t:Mailbox>
                      <t:ItemId Id="AAMkADZmMjJ..." ChangeKey="EQAAABYA..." />
                    </t:Mailbox>
                  </t:Member>
                  <t:Member>
                    <t:Mailbox>
                      <t:EmailAddress>user@contonso.com</t:EmailAddress>
                    </t:Mailbox>
                  </t:Member>
                </t:Members>
              </t:DistributionList>
            </t:AppendToItemField>
          </t:Updates>
        </t:ItemChange>
      </ItemChanges>
    </UpdateItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```